# How do I make the hard drive visible in the Finder?

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, hard-drive

On OS X Lion I don't see the hard drive in the Finder and I seem to have no permission to create a folder under / from terminal.

I know I can do this if I activate the root user, but I need to be able to see the directories I have created under / in the Finder.

How can I be able to make my main hard drive visible in the Finder?

Comment: Are you asking about Lion or Mountain Lion? Your text says one thing and your tag another.

Answer (score 65):

1. While in the Finder, go to the "Finder" menu and select "Preferences".
2. From the "General" tab, place a check next to "Hard disks" -- this will make your hard drive visible on the Desktop.
3. From the "Sidebar" tab under "Devices" again place a check next to "Hard disks" -- this will put your hard drive in the sidebar of any finder window, and should also add it to "Open", "Save", and "Save As..." dialog sheets (as well as others)

If you are an administrator on the computer you should have no trouble adding files and folders to the root directory (/)

Comment: Finder > Preferences > Sidebar:check "hard disks" under "Locations."

Answer (score 9):

This was troubling me for a while on my wife's computer. I had *everything* checked in preferences and it still wasn't showing up.

Then I found that if you rollover **Devices** on the sidebar in the `Finder` window, there's a little **Show** and **Hide** that pops up.

Comment: OMG! That's so stupid!! You save my ass!!!

Answer (score 5):

Launch Finder then just press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

This is effectively like ‘My Computer’ in Windows. It will give you a list of all the connected drives on your Mac, both internally and externally connected drives as well as Network drives.

Comment: Where did you find this mystical incantation?

Answer (score 0):

1. While in the Finder, go to the "Finder" menu and select
   "Preferences".
2. Add the name of your MacBook to the Sidebar.
3. Click on the name of your MacBook and drag your hard drive or
   `untitled` to the Sidebar.